# SystemJS Error with Angular AOT: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ctor is not a constructor

Tags: angular, systemjs, ng-bootstrap, angular-compiler-cli, angular-compiler

I'm using **Angular 4.4.1 + SystemJS 0.20.19 + NgBootstrap 1.0.0-beta.5** in an app. The app works in **Angular JIT** mode by following this [instructions](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) and having the following **SystemJS** configuration

`meta: {
        "./*": {
            "esModule": true
        }
    }`

I used **"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json** to compile the app into an **AOT** app.

In the **AOT** app, I have the the **SystemJS** `map` configuration as shown at the end of this question.

The same app that worked in JIT mode does not work in the AOT mode, and generates the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
    at _createClass (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.umd.min.js:210)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at _createClass (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.umd.min.js:210)
    at resolveDep (core.umd.min.js:97)
    at _createClass (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.umd.min.js:210)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at _createClass (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.umd.min.js:90)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.umd.min.js:210)
    at resolveDep (core.umd.min.js:97)
    at resolvePromise (config.ts:60)
    at resolvePromise (config.ts:60)
    at config.ts:60
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (config.ts:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.min.js:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (config.ts:60)
    at Zone.runTask (config.ts:60)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (config.ts:60)
    at <anonymous>
```

Questions:

1. I have no way of knowing which module is causing this error. After numerous debugging, the error comes while the `NgBootstrao NgbModel` is loading. How to fix this error?
2. Is there some configuration settings that I can use to see the progress/log of the modules that **SystemJS** is loading in the browser console?

**SystemJS Map for NgBootstrap:**

```
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-stack":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/progressbar/progressbar-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/ngb-calendar":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-i18n":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/ngb-date-parser-formatter":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pagination/pagination-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tabset/tabset-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker-config":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/buttons.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/collapse/collapse.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/progressbar/progressbar.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-input":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pagination/pagination.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tabset/tabset.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.module":  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js , 
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/index" :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/highlight  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-window  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-backdrop  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-day-view  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-month-view  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-navigation  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-service  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-keymap-service  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-navigation-select  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-ref  :  /lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js ,
```

Comment: The problem leads to the dependency resolution for ```NgbModal```. A new bug report entered in the [angular GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19313).

Comment: did you ever get AOT working with systemjs?